# Why my Asus ROG Gl702zc will not connect to my second monitor?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, asus-laptop

I have recently bought the Asus ROG GL702zc laptop, and I want to connect it to my HP S2031a monitor.

Since both these devices don't share any port, I have tried to connect it by an HDMI cable and HDMI to DVI-D Adaptor, and with the old computer worked just fine.

Basically, on the HP screen it tell me to check the cable, and windows 10 was able to detect the second monitor, but it just would show anything.

Can you tell me how to solve my problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following way：

Press **Windows Key + P**：Easy Display Switcher

Choose Projection mode and switch to a projector or duplicate displays.

[image]

**Computer only** is the default option–and the name says it all.

**Duplicate** clones your screen to a connected secondary display, monitor or projector.

**Extend** expands the desktop so you can make room for extra windows.

**Projector only** turns off your laptop's LCD and turns the projector into your monitor.

If it does not work above, we try to update or reinstall the latest display card driver according to our laptop model.

Comment: I have already done all of these steps, with the sole result that the screen shows Check Video Cable

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answers (with plural 's' ):

1. Check HDMI to DVI adapter, sometime they can't handle the conversion.
2. HP S2031a monitors have a option in their menu that gives you the choice of selecting the input signal port, make sure it's automatic or that it have been correctly selected with.

PS: Make sure that you update monitor's driver to to be able to enjoy a 1600x900 px view